# How to enable Code Assist for ColdFusion builder 2.0.1?

Tags: coldfusion, autocomplete, code-assist, coldfusionbuilder

I tried my best to enable the code assist in ColdFusion builder 2.0.1 but no luck.

I found two helping pages:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/2.0/Using/WS0ef8c004658c1089-554789f8121af8f0c8c-7ffb.html

and

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/2.0/Using/WSf01dbd23413dda0e1736ebc1213a528ab0-7ffb.html#WS0ef8c004658c1089794dbeb6124c7814753-8000

what I am looking for is to let the coldFusion Builder assist me by auto-completing the REQUEST, SESSION, & APPLICATIONS variables. I tried the follow the instructions in the second link but it didn't work, maybe I wrote some incorrect data?

If any one managed to let it work, please help me.
[image: ColdFusion Builder 2.0.1 CFC Mappings]

Comment: I doubt it can populate request/session/application scopes.  It's not a feature one should count.  Code Assist can only inspect the CFC and give you a dropdown of methods that CFC *should* have.

Comment: looks like because ColdFusion is not OOP Language it will be difficult for the IDE to implement the full support of Code Assist for the copes I mentioned!

That is too sad, I thought Coldfusion Builder has this feature, this is the main reason I bought it, otherwise I would continue using DreamWeaver =(

Comment: This definitely CAN be made to work, because when I was still using CFB I had it working. However it relies on having one's project set up in a very specific (and non particularly "real world") way. I cannot remember the details, and no longer have CFB installed, so cannot revisit it for you. But do you have a CF server configured and assigned to your project? That's needed for this stuff to work.

Comment: It was inappropriate to close this, guys "Questions about [...] software are off-topic [...] *unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming*" (my *emphasis*). CFB is a tool used primarily  - EXCLUSIVELY even - for programming. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have set up the server correctly in CF Builder, it will talk to the server and cache the respond of what methods does a CFC have.  (Console Tab: "Server is available. Getting server settings.")

E.g. If `Person.cfc` has property Name and Age with `accessors=true`, and you type `p = new Person()`, then "p." (Ctrl+Space) should see `getAge()`, `getName()`, `setAge()`, `setName()`.  If you got that to work, you have set it up correctly.

As for variables in REQUEST, SESSION, & APPLICATIONS scopes, I think CFB would see if you have referenced them before on the same .cfm and may give you autocomplete, but don't count on it to be smart enough to know exactly what variables are there in the scopes.

Comment: The person.cfc example is working fine. My problem is with other variables, they are not working... I will check server setting as Adam mentioned.